# Find using Aggregate documents where date can be in multiple ranges

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to write a query that filters based on an array of date ranges and returns the documents where birthday field is in one of those ranges:

```
const users = await User.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          birthday: {
            $or: [
              {
                $lte: "1998-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                $gte: "1997-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
              },
              {
                $lte: "2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                $gte: "2001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
              },
              {
                $lte: "2002-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                $gte: "2003-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    ])
```

But, that returns this error:

> error MongoError: unknown operator: $or

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator is a top-level operator, It will perform logical `$or` operation on an array of expressions, while you need to specify the whole condition with fields name in an array of object/element, event if its same field, you need to repeat it in all elements of array,

correct the syntax as below,

```
{
    $match: {
        $or: [
            {
                birthday: {
                    $lte: "1998-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                    $gte: "1997-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
                }
            },
            {
                birthday: {
                    $lte: "2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                    $gte: "2001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
                }
            },
            {
                birthday: {
                    $lte: "2002-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                    $gte: "2003-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```